# Do DirectX Compute Shaders support 2D arrays in shared memory?

Tags: directx, compute-shader, directcompute

I want to use `groupshared` memory in a DirectX Compute Shader to reduce global memory bandwidth and hopefully improve performance. My input data is a `Texture2D` and I can access it using 2D indexing like so:

```
Input[threadID.xy]
```

I would like to have a 2D array of shared memory for caching portions of the input data, so I tried the obvious:

```
groupshared float SharedInput[32, 32];
```

It won't compile. The error message says `syntax error: unexpected token ','`.

Is there any way to have a 2D array of shared memory? If not, what's a good technique for working with 2D data stored in a 1D array of shared memory?

Comment: Have you tried [][]? Even DX9c HLSL supports it, so with some imagination, compute shaders should do too.

Comment: I have not tried `[][]`. That would make an array of arrays, which is different than a 2D array. Indexing wouldn't be as nice as 2D indexing, but better than linear indexing. I wonder if there's any performance difference compared to one linear array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupshared` arrays cannot be indexed with multi-dimensional indexing. The closest you can get is an array of arrays where each dimension is indexed independently.

```
groupshared float SharedInput[32][32];
```

It's not as nice as multi-dimensional indexing, but at least you don't have to compute a linear index manually.